# Widget does not fit in Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a widget which was made for Android 2.3. 
It has these dimensions:

```
android:minHeight="76dip"
android:minWidth="146dip"
```

The problem is that Google has changed the height of a cell in Jelly Bean or even in ICS.
A cell is now 40dp and 2 cells 110dp. This makes my widget streched to 110dp. This looks very ugly as it is streched a lot. 
If I increase the fontsize on my widget and the spaces, I can make it fit in the 110dp height. But then it will look ugly on Android 2.3.

I am wondering how I can adapt the widget to look nice on JB AND on Android 2.3. Is there a recommended guide?

Answer (score 0):

Every device may have a different grid size. The only foolproof solution is to use flexible layouts, [9-patch drawables](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), etc.